# Converting my delays to millis for smoother operation

Tags: arduino-uno, teensy

I need help converting my code to change out the `delay()` command into the `millis()` command for smoother operation.

Currently the code only moves after the delay is up. I would like the codes to run simultaneously.

This is my codes

```
#define aref_voltage 3.3
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels
// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
#define OLED_RESET     4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
Servo Servo1;
int led = 13;
int sw = 3;
int bz = 14;
int ldr = A1;
int lv = 0;
int rly = 7;
int buttonState = 0;
int servoPin = 8;
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() 
{
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sw, INPUT);
  pinMode(ldr, INPUT);
  pinMode(bz, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rly, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(rly, LOW);
   Servo1.attach(servoPin);
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  Serial.begin(115200);

   if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { // Address 0x3D for 128x64
   Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
   for(;;);
  }
}
void loop() 
  {
  lv = analogRead(ldr); // read the value off the LDR
  Serial.print("LDR Value is: ");
  Serial.println(lv);
  delay(100);
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(sw); // Check switch 1 or 0
  Serial.println(buttonState);   //Show the state of pushbutton on serial monitor  
  delay(100);
  
    while ( (lv >= 150) && (buttonState == HIGH) )
{
    delay(1000);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(2); 
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.println("Relay On! ");      // here the message is inside the "" 
    delay(1000);
    display.display();

    digitalWrite(rly, HIGH);//relay on 1 min
    delay(6000);
    tone(bz, 1500);//buzzer on for 30 sec
    delay(3000); 
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);//led flash at 1 Hz
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(3000);

    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // led 2 kHz
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(3000);
    tone(bz, 2000); //buzzer at 2 khz
    delay(3000);
    noTone(bz);

    delay(2000);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(2); 
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.println("Tank 2 Filled! ");      // here the message is inside the "" 
    delay(1000);
    display.display();
    
    digitalWrite(rly, LOW); // relay low
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
    delay(5000);            // led flash 4Hz
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(5000);

   Servo1.write(45); // Make servo go to 45 degrees 
   delay(1000);
   
   Servo1.write(135); // Make servo go to 135 degrees
   delay(1000);
   
   Servo1.write(0); // Make servo go to 0 degrees 
   delay(1000);
    break;
}
   if (buttonState == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(rly, LOW); // relay off
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); // led off
    delay(500); 
   Servo1.write(0);     // Make servo go to 0 degrees 
   delay(1000);
    noTone(bz); // buzzer off

  }
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem in doing that? Have you understood how the `millis()` function is used? Do you know, what an FSM (Finite State Machine) is? If not, you should really search for it, since that concept will be incredible helpful in implementing, what you want.

Comment: The codes only move after the delay is up, i would like the codes to run simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, thats a very general description, of what you want. But it doesn't explain, what exactly the problem is. What have you tried so far? Is there something, that you don't understand in the concept of non-blocking code like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example (thats the example explaining `millis()`)? There is already tons of tutorials on the web about this and we need to know, how we can help you better than these.

Comment: You have posted a goal, not a question.This site is not a free coding service. You should do a Google search on "Arduino blink without delay", read one of the various tutorials that search finds, and then attempt to refactor your code yourself.

Comment: ok thanks for the info

Comment: your code is cluttered with useless comments ... for example `//led flash at 1 Hz` comments a section of code that does not operate at 1 Hz ... same thing with a lot of the other comments

Comment: you need to think clearly about how your code flows ... as it stands now, it is filled with silly comands (my apologies for the choice of words, but i cannot think of any other word) ... example in pseudo code: `relay ON`, `wait 6 seconds`, `buzzer ON`, `wait 3 seconds`, `led ON`, `wait 3 seconds`,  `led OFF`, `wait 3 seconds`, etc. etc.  ..... simpler code would be `relay ON`, `buzzer ON`, `led ON`, `wait 3 seconds`,  `led OFF`, `wait 3 seconds`, etc. etc

Comment: @DuncanC his goal is to get rid of delays and make the code run smoothly, I thought he explained that.

Answer (score 1):

Your delays are making the program jerky, so you have to get rid of them. :)

I have a [lengthy discussion about this](http://gammon.com.au/blink) on my own web site, but basically you need to restructure so that you use a "state machine" and instead of delaying, make a note of the current time (using millis() function) and then do the next step when the time is up.

Just as an example, when you bake a cake you don't stop what you are doing for an hour and stare at the oven while it cooks, do you? You make a note of the time, and come back when the time is up.

One of the Arduino tutorials [Blink without delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay) has an example of doing that.

The example code is (initial comments removed):

```
// constants won't change. Used here to set a pin number:
const int ledPin =  LED_BUILTIN;// the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change:
const long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the difference
  // between the current time and last time you blinked the LED is bigger than
  // the interval at which you want to blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

This won't be a one-line change. You have to re-think how you go about handling time delays.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote an [answer to another question about non-blocking programming](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/60759/how-to-rotate-two-or-more-steppers-simultaneously-by-giving-array-of-angles/66380#66380), using "maybe-do" functions - functions that maybe do something if the conditions for doing it are met, typically a time-interval having passed. @nickgammon's excellent article (linked in his answer to this question) shows a similar structure that evaluates the condition within loop() rather than within the maybe-do/action function, as I did in my answer. Both ways work equally well.

It will be a good exercise to play with the BlinkWithoutDelay example sketch, and even write a couple of your own sketches that follow that general format. But soon you'll get tired of writing all of those `if( (millis() - previousMills) >= someInterval){` expressions and the bookkeeping of the various `previousMillis`es that goes with them - not to mention debugging the results of the inevitable typos! )-:

Once you've got the hang of:

```
is (current time - time when we previously acted) >= action interval{
   do the action;
   save the current time as the previous time;
}
// again, for the next action
// yet again, for each remaining action
```

, consider using a timer library such as SimpleTimer. Its job is to maintain all that bookkeeping for you, and to call your action functions at the right time.

You need to know a few things to use it - some of the same few things you needed to know to write code the previous way, but the more tedious parts will be done for you:

- How to make a set of timers;
- How to make an action function (called a 'callback function');
- How to set an interval (one-time or repeating) that the action- or callback-function will get called.
- How to run the timers so they can do their jobs.

**How to make timers**:

- First, you need the library: Visit this [github page](https://github.com/marcelloromani/Arduino-SimpleTimer) and click the green "Download Code" button (it's really a down-arrow, not the word "download"). In the menu that appears, click "Download ZIP".
- Open the file that you receive, "Arduino-SimpleTimer-master.zip" (how you do this depends on your computer's operating system). In the .zip file you'll find this folder structure: 
  `Arduino-SimpleTimer-master --- SimpleTimer --- (some folders and files)`
  Drag the 'SimpleTimer' folder into the 'libraries' folder within your Arduino sketch folder. This library can serve every sketch you write from now on.
- Add the following include file to the top of your sketch:
  `#include <SimpleTimer.h>`
- Create a global set of timers:
  `SimpleTimer myTimers;`  // creates 10 timers and makes them available for use.

**How to make a callback function** - the function that runs your LED, stepper motor, or whatever other action you need taken at a certain time:

- A callback function does whatever is necessary to complete the timed task, *and nothing more*. For example, it might toggle an LED off if it is on, or on if it is off.
- An action function takes *no arguments* and *returns no value*. It *must have the type*:
  `void toggleLED(void);`
  Of course, you get to name your functions whatever you like.

**How to set an interval.** There are a number of ways, but you're likely to use these two for nearly everything - repeating, or one-time:

- `myTimers.setTimeout(time, toggleLED);`
   sets a one-time timer that
  will call my `toggleLED()' function *once* only, after "time" milliseconds. It returns the timer number that will be used. Mostly you can ignore that value for now.
- `myTimers.setInterval(time, toggleLED);`
   sets a repeating timer that will keep calling my `toggleLED()` function *every* "time" milliseconds, for as long as the sketch runs. It also returns the timer number, and again, you can ignore that value for now.

**How to run the timers.**

- The timer library needs to be called **frequently** for your functions to get called at fairly precise intervals. Your `loop()` function should call `myTimers.run()` each time it runs.
- `loop()` should not do anything that takes very long, nor call any function that can take very long. Long tasks will disturb the precision of the timing with which your callback functions get called.
- Your loop function should look like:

```
void loop(){
   myTimers.run();
   // maybe some other fast code here
}
```

The `.run()` function checks each of your timers, and for every one whose time has expired, it calls its callback function (the one you specified when you called `.setInterval()` or `.setTimeout()`). This is how the timer library does its work, and why you need to call it frequently.

Now let's look put it all together in a **sample program to blink 2 LED's** at different intervals using SimpleTimers:

```
// SimpleTimer demo program
//    Blink 2 LEDs at different rates for 15 seconds, then turn off both LEDs and stop.

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

/*****< Definitions >*****/
#define LED1    13  // the on-board LED
#define LED2    12  // an external LED



/*****< External and Global Declarations >*****/
SimpleTimer myTimers;       // define a set of timers
bool doHalt = false;            // a flag to tell loop() to stop


/*****< Local Function Prototypes >*****/
void toggleLED1(void);      // function to toggle the state of LED1
void toggleLED2(void);      // function to toggle the state of LED2
void setHalt(void);         // function to set the halt flag

void setup()
{
    // Set the pin modes for our two LEDs:
   pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);

   // Turn off the LEDs:
   digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);

    // Set up the blink intervals
    myTimers.setInterval(800L, toggleLED1); // start timer to blink LED1 slowly
    myTimers.setInterval(300L, toggleLED2); // start timer to blink LED2 rapidly

    // Stop the program after 30 seconds.
    myTimers.setTimeout(15*1000L, setHalt); // start timer to halt the program
}


void loop() {
    myTimers.run();                 // keep calling the timers as often as possible

    if( doHalt ){                       // if the halt flag is set,
        // Turn off the LEDs:
       digitalWrite(LED1, LOW); //    shut off the leds,
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);

    // Hang here, doing nothing
        while(1)                            //    and hang here forever.
            ;
    }
}

// Toggle the state of LED1
void toggleLED1(void){
    bool isOn = digitalRead(LED1);
    
    digitalWrite(LED1, !isOn);
}


// Toggle the state of LED2
void toggleLED2(void){
    bool isOn = digitalRead(LED2);
    
    digitalWrite(LED2, !isOn);
}


// Set the halt flag to stop 'loop()'
void setHalt(void){
    doHalt = true;
}

/***  end  ***/
```

This program does everything BlinkWithoutDelay does, but without the bookkeeping and the mechanics of calling your action functions. Those are all taken care of by the SimpleTimer library, leaving you free to concentrate on what your program is meant to do.